Can we conditionally manage the dynamic config value in the app router page (next.js 14)?
I was trying to add this on a page:
export const dynamic = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_PLATFORM === "mobileApplication" ? "force-static" : "auto";
But I came across this warning and red underline:

TS71003: "process. env. NEXT_PUBLIC_PLATFORM === "mobileApplication" ?
"force-static" : "auto"" is not a valid value for the "dynamic"
option. The configuration must be statically analyzable.

But it seems that this condition will work, but I don't know what this error is talking about
